# Laravel Migration to a new Server/DB

Tags: laravel, migration

I am trying to migrate to a new DB in a different host. However, when I run `php artisan migrate`, it's giving me an error. Laravel is looking for a specific table(permissions table in this case, I have eloquent relationships set up) in my app. Obviously, a new DB is completely empty. How can I run the migration to a new DB in a new host? What am I missing here?

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cf.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions`)


In PDOConnection.php line 63:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cf.permissions' doesn't exist


In PDOConnection.php line 61:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cf.permissions' doesn't exist
```

Permission Migration File;

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePermissionRoles extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('permission_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('permissions')
                   /* ->onDelete('cascade') */
;

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('roles')
                    /* ->onDelete('cascade') */
;

            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
        });

        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('roles')
                    /* ->onDelete('cascade') */
;

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users')
                    /* ->onDelete('cascade') */
;

            $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('permissions');
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
        Schema::dropIfExists('permission_role');
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

AppServiceProvider File;

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
    }
}

protected function getPermissions()
{
    return Permission::with('roles')->get();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that queries the database in one of your service providers?

Comment: not that I am aware of, How can I be sure, if this is the issue?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are querying the `Table` table in your database. Do you get a stacktrace? If so, can you post it?

Comment: I think the order of executions of your migration files is the issue. It is trying to create child tables before a master table.

Comment: @vivek_23 In my permissions migration file, I am creating permissions table first  then creating the pivot table with foreign keys referencing the main permissions table.  What's the order of execution? Dates of the files in migrations folder?

Comment: @Jerodev I maybe misunderstanding what a "stacktrace" is but I updated the post with full error output.

Comment: @eleven0 Can you show your migration file?

Comment: @vivek_23 I just updated the post with migration file.

Comment: Put the tables on diferents migrations

Comment: @JoaoGRRR Just tried, same error.

Comment: @eleven0 I ran your migration on my machine and it went well without any hassle. Are you sure you came across this when you ran `php artisan migrate` or were you visiting some webpage and this came up?

Comment: @vivek_23 I haven't touched that migration file since the very beginning of project start date. I changed my mysql server and i started receiving the error in the post. I think Jerodev had the correct idea, My code is querying Permission table before migration.  It's a system wide error, I cant even do "php artisan serve" or "composer install"....

Comment: @eleven0 `My code is querying Permission table before migration`. Of course, there could be many reasons. First one is to make sure no other migration file is using `Permissions` table. Second, don't do `php artisan serve` without setting up the database or at least it's required tables for initial requests.

Comment: @vivek_23 okay, I just checked all other migration files, no other migrate file is using permissions table. What else can I do to solve this? Can I see this file in details, In Connection.php line 664:? How could i retrieve this?

Comment: @eleven0 you could but that won't be of any help. Would you mind creating a git repo and share the link?

Comment: @vivek_23 I updated the post with AppserviceProvider file, when I comment that out and run migrations.. I am able to run migrations and all is back to normal. After the initial migration, i can run the migration with above code. I need that for my permissions structure. How can I set it up so that I dont have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your `getPermissions()` method, check if your schema `permissions` and `roles` exists and return values accordingly using [Schema's hasTable()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#checking-existence) method. This way migrate commands would not hinder with service provider's methods.

Note that once the 2 tables are set(after a successful migration), this action from your service provider will always be executed.

```
<?php


protected function getPermissions(){
    if(Schema::hasTable('permissions') && Schema::hasTable('roles')){
        return Permission::with('roles')->get();
    }

    return collect([]);
}
```